# Non-cyclotomic modular fusion categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, subfactors, fusion-categories, modular-tensor-categories

In a recent talk (see [1]) Richard Ng asks whether the invariants of 3-manifolds derived from any modular fusion category are cyclotomic integers. In tqft, such an invariant is computed from the F-symbols of a modular fusion category. The F-symbols depend on the choice of bases for the hom spaces, but the invariant is independent of the choice (see the book [2] by Vladimir Turaev and Alexis Virelizier).

A fusion category is called *cyclotomic* if there exist bases of the hom spaces for which the F-symbols are all cyclotomic numbers. In [3] Scott Morrison and Noah Snyder provided non-cyclotomic fusion categories, namely the principal even part of the Haagerup and extended Haagerup subfactors; they also proved that the Drinfeld center of the first one is cyclotomic (and they expect so for the second, but it is still unknown).

**Question 1**: Is there a non-cyclotomic modular fusion categories?

It is a weaker version of Richard's question mentioned above, because a negative answer to Question 1 answers Richard's question positively, whereas a positive answer to Question 1 let Richard's question open (because a sum of non-cyclotomic numbers can be cyclotomic).

The Drinfeld center of the Extended Haagerup category (mentioned above) is a candidate, but it is expected to be cyclotomic. This leads to the following question:

**Question 2**: Is the Drinfeld center of a fusion category always cyclotomic?

---

*References*

[1] R. Ng, *Arithmetic of Modular Tensor Categories*, Dec. 2021, https://www.math.ucsc.edu/seminars/colloquium.html#dec2
[2] V. Turaev, A. Virelizier, *Monoidal categories and topological field theory*. Progress in Mathematics, 322 (2017) xii+523 pp.
[3] S. Morrison, N. Snyder, *Non-cyclotomic fusion categories.* Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 364 (2012), no. 9, 4713--4733.

Answer (score 3):

A detailed discussion of your question can be found in Davidovitch et. al's paper "[On arithmetic modular tensor categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.2229.pdf)". They say that it is still an open problem whether there are non-cyclotomic modular tensor categories. However, they do conjecture formally (conjecture 4.5) that every MTC is cyclotomic. I am not aware of any significant recent progress on the conjecture.